# FontFaceSet : check Could not resolve font family names including digits

Tags: javascript, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts, webfont-loader

I'm using the google font API to retrieves all google fonts. I got all the fonts as a Object contains each font item like the following :

```
{
    "family" : "Roboto",
    "variants" : ["100", "100italic", "300", "300italic"],
    ...
},
{...}
```

Now I use the [WebFonts Loader Package](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) to load the fonts. But I want to check if the font is already loaded in the document (to avoid load the same font twice) : Using this function :

```
const isFontLoaded = (fontName) => {
    const fontNameFormated = fontName.split(':')[0].replaceAll('+', ' '); // Formatting any font name like Open+Sans:100,300italic to Open Sans

    return document.fonts.check('16px ' + fontNameFormated);
};
```

The output was :

```
fonts.js:129 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'check' on 'FontFaceSet': Could 
not resolve '16px M PLUS Rounded 1c' as a font.
```

What I noticed is that the error only appears when a font family has a name including a digit. Like M PLUS Rounded 1c, Exo 2 ...

Plus when I add the following regex `.replaceAll(/[0-9]/g, '');` to remove all digits on each font family name, it work's correctly. But now the `document.fonts.check` method return false (probably because the font name is invalid).

Test :

```js
const fonts = ['Roboto', 'M PLUS Rounded c', 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', 'Exo 2'];

fonts.forEach((font) => {
   console.log(font, document.fonts.check('16px ' + font)); 
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your font name in quotes, which would be true if used for CSS too.

```js
const fonts = ['Roboto', '"M PLUS Rounded c"', '"M PLUS Rounded 1c"', '"Exo 2"'];

fonts.forEach((font) => {
   console.log(font, document.fonts.check('16px ' + font)); 
})
```